# IDA eh vector constructor iterator

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, ida

i try to decomplile some class via IDA pro, and see this:

```
`eh vector constructor iterator'(
(char *)this->ObtainPickItemList,
28u,
12,
(void (__thiscall *)(void *))std::string::string,
std::string::~string);
```

I know 'this->ObtainPickItemList' is std::string array with 12 elements, but what is 28?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`28` should be the size of individual `std::string` object, that is what `sizeof(std::string)` would return for that particular `std::string` implementation that was compiled into the binary you're trying to decompile.

Note, that the size might or might not be different from what `sizeof(std::string)` returns when you try compiling on your platform.